# Android lag double view

Tags: android, lag

I'm making an apps one feature is to show a flash and a litle html banner.

The banner switch to next banner once the texte has go frome right to left so i can't make it in one web view

I have make two of them it's work

But when the flash is animated the banner stop scrolling and lag to much

I have read i can't modify UI in another thread so
How can i reduce lag without make a new thread?

For banner scroll i use a Interval of 10 in the function 
    setInterval();

Comment: What device are you testing on? You could try turning hardwareAcceleration on in your manifest. Sounds like you are hitting a performance limit on your specific device though, I doubt there is any way you are going to get it much better if the device simply isn't strong enough to handle the multiple animations.

Comment: A mini pc Android

A key form with hdmi port  DDR31Go  Cortex-A8/Dual !core 1.6Ghz Cortex A9